# WPF IDataErrorInfo process error array

Tags: wpf, arrays, validation, idataerrorinfo

I´m using `IDataErrorInfo` for validation in WPF, But when the attribute is an array I can to process the error. ( in this case `int[] Position`)

My code is similar to this: http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/

```
   public class Customer : IDataErrorInfo
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public int[] Position { get; set; }

        #region IDataErrorInfo Members

        public string Error
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                string result = null;

               if (columName == "FirstName")
               {
                  // Do something
               }

               if (columnName == "Position")
                {

                    // Do something
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

XAML

```
    <TextBox x:Name="tbFirstName" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="left" 
                         Validation.Error="Validation_Error" MaxLength="2"
                         Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                         Path=FirstName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true,    NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />

    <TextBox x:Name="tbPosition1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="left" 
                     Validation.Error="Validation_Error" MaxLength="2"
                     Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                     Path=Position[0], ValidatesOnDataErrors=true,    NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
```

I have no problem to capture "Firstname" but if I do a change in the textbox of btPosition1 the program don´t through the function to process the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You bind to an item in array, not to array itself.
In this case, I think, WPF looks for IDataErrorInfo in Array class.
So you should either expose positions as separate properties (if they are finite), or use your own collection class: inherit List<> and add IDataErrorInfo implementation.